# passing an object with json data

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, view, controller

I am using `jsonData` to bind to a `jqgrid` but I also want to use `model.total amount` in a field.

So how can I return it with `jsonData` to use it inside this `<td>`?

**View**

```
<table>
<tr>

<td>@Model.TotalAmount</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult GetDocPendingDetails(string strPA, string strEmpCode, string StrModeOfPayment) // Sends PA to bind the gridview
        {
            string StrEmpcode = ""; // to be changed
            cmn_top objCmn_top = new cmn_top();
            DataTable dtData = new DataTable();
            Items objitem = new Items();
            if (StrModeOfPayment == "All")
            {
                StrModeOfPayment = "";
            }
            dtData = objCmn_top.Reports_GetData__DocPendingPayment(strPA, StrEmpcode, StrModeOfPayment);
            ViewBag.TotalAmount = dtData.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => x.Field<double>("fl_approvedamt")).ToString();           // to be changed later
            int totalRecords = dtData.Rows.Count;
            var jsonData = new
            {
                totalamount = ViewBag.TotalAmount,
                total = totalRecords,
                rows =
                (
                from dtRow in dtData.AsEnumerable()
                select new
                {
                    cell = new string[]
                    {                       
                       dtRow.Field<string>("ch_docno"),dtRow.Field<string>("ch_empcode"),dtRow.Field<string>("ch_sapvoucherno"), dtRow.Field<string>("CH_PSA_CODE"),dtRow.Field<double>("fl_approvedamt").ToString()
                    }
                }
                )
            };
            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

**This is my jqgrid**

```
    $("#list").GridUnload();
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url: '/Reports/GetDocPendingDetails',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['Document No.', 'Document Owner', 'SAP Document No', 'PSA', 'Approved Amount'],
        colModel: [
              { name: 'ch_docno', index: 'ch_docno', width: 100, align: 'center' },
              { name: 'ch_empcode', index: 'ch_empcode', width: 250, align: 'left' },
              { name: 'ch_sapvoucherno', index: 'ch_sapvoucherno', width: 100, align: 'center' },
              { name: 'CH_PSA_CODE', index: 'CH_PSA_CODE', width: 200, align: 'left' },
                 { name: 'fl_approvedamt', index: 'fl_approvedamt', width: 100, align: 'center' }

            ],
        emptyrecords: "Empty records",
        height: 'auto',
        loadtext: 'Loading.....',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        caption: " Documents Pending For Payment ",
        shrinkToFit: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        rowNum: -1,
        postData: { strPA: selectedPA, StrModeOfPayment: modeOfPayment },
        viewrecords: true,
        gridComplete: function () {
            var recs = parseInt($("#list").getGridParam("records"));
            if (isNaN(recs) || recs == 0) {
                $("#gridWrapper").hide();
                $("#DivEmptyRecords").show();

            }
            else {
                $('#gridWrapper').show();
                $("#DivEmptyRecords").hide();

            }
        }
    });
//document.getElementById("tdTotalAmount").innerHTML = jsonData.TotalAmount;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning JsonData right ? You cannot use `@Model.TotalAmount` in this case.

If you want to use `@Model.TotalAmount` have your action return a Model which has TotalAmount as a property in it.

But as you need to use Jqgrid I suggest you stick with returning `Json` data.

Also I can see that you are passing `totalamount` as a part of the Json result.

Use firefox's firebug and investigate how and what json data is posted, and then use that values with jquery and jqgrid.

Also it would be better if you could post some of your Jqgrid code too.

Comment: hi i have posted the jqgrid code, i want to use TotalAmount at the place of @model.totalamount . I am just confused how to access the json data at that place.